# Extract Cyrillic letters from string

Tags: r, regex, grepl

The function below extracts any letters from the english alphabet from a string.

```
is.letter <- function(x) grepl("[:alpha:]", x)
```

I want to build a similar function that extracts only cyrlic letters from a given string.

Update:

With the code provided by Wiktor Stribiżew, I get the following results:

```
grepl("\\p{Cyrillic}", x, perl=TRUE)

test[, c(2, 11)]
      MOBILE_NUMBER contain_cyrlic
    1  НЕМА ТЕЛЕФОН          FALSE
    2      НЕПОЗНАТ          FALSE
    3  НЕМА ТЕЛЕФОН          FALSE
    4  НЕМА ТЕЛЕФОН          FALSE
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `grepl("\\p{Cyrillic}", x, perl=TRUE)`.

Comment: Hmm.. it returns false for all entries, even those containing cyrlic letters. Could it be the encoding?

Comment: Could you please share some strings you test against (the testing code)?

Comment: `grepl("\\p{Cyrillic}", c("НЕМА ТЕЛЕФОН", "abc", "НЕПОЗНАТ", "def"), perl = TRUE)` works correctly for me. @Prometheus What does `pcre_config()` return for you? The help file `?pcre_config` notes that **Unicode properties** indicates whether or not ` \p{xx}` and `\P{xx}` constructs are supported.

Comment: @nrussell pcre_config() returns TRUE for UTF-8, Unicode properties and JIT. The stri_detect_regex function shown below did the trick though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stringi` might provide more cross-platform/system consistent results for you but both `stri_detect_regex` and `grepl` (in "perl" mode) should do the trick:

```
library(stringi)
library(dplyr)

data_frame(
  MOBILE_NUMBER = c("НЕМА ТЕЛЕФОН", "НЕПОЗНАТ", "НЕМА ТЕЛЕФОН", "НЕМА ТЕЛЕФОН")
) -> tst

tst
## # A tibble: 4 × 1
##   MOBILE_NUMBER
##           <chr>
## 1  НЕМА ТЕЛЕФОН
## 2      НЕПОЗНАТ
## 3  НЕМА ТЕЛЕФОН
## 4  НЕМА ТЕЛЕФОН

(t1 <- mutate(tst, is_cyrillic = grepl("\\p{Cyrillic}", MOBILE_NUMBER, perl=TRUE)))
## # A tibble: 4 × 2
##   MOBILE_NUMBER is_cyrillic
##           <chr>       <lgl>
## 1  НЕМА ТЕЛЕФОН        TRUE
## 2      НЕПОЗНАТ        TRUE
## 3  НЕМА ТЕЛЕФОН        TRUE
## 4  НЕМА ТЕЛЕФОН        TRUE

(t2 <- mutate(tst, is_cyrillic = stri_detect_regex(MOBILE_NUMBER, "\\p{Cyrillic}")))

## # A tibble: 4 × 2
##   MOBILE_NUMBER is_cyrillic
##           <chr>       <lgl>
## 1  НЕМА ТЕЛЕФОН        TRUE
## 2      НЕПОЗНАТ        TRUE
## 3  НЕМА ТЕЛЕФОН        TRUE
## 4  НЕМА ТЕЛЕФОН        TRUE

identical(t1, t2)
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: The stri_detect_regex function worked. But grepl returns false, as I mentioned previouslly. Thanks for the help!